# Assuring that buffer access is private using openmp

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

Suppose I have the following function:

```
void fun (){

#pragma omp parallel private(i, x, d0, d1)
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            d0 = calc_dist();
            d1 = calc_dist();
            x = ((d0 < d1) ? 0 : 1);
            buffer1[i] = x;

            #pragma omp atomic update
            group_size[x] += 1;


        } 

    }
}
```

I want to know if accessing buffer1 `buffer1[i] = x` is still private having the fact that `i` and `x` are set to be private variables in the pragma section? If not, is it possible to allow buffer access private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example access to `buffer1[i] = x;` is fine. It works because in the work-sharing loop, no two threads will ever get the same `i` and therefore no two threads will ever access the same memory.

Note that technically, `buffer1[i]` is *not private*, private applies only to variables. `buffer1` is a *shared variable*.

You **must not** access any other element of `buffer1` in any way within the loop. E.g. **do not** do anything like `foo = buffer1[i-1]`.

This all works for regular C arrays or pointers, but there must not be any aliasing in effect.